# In Emacs 24.3.1 on Windows 7, how can I group directories first in dired?

Tags: sorting, emacs, dired

I have recently started to use `dired` in earnest, having belatedly checked out the advice to use <kbd>C-x C-j</kbd> given in one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396967/emacs-what-are-good-tactics-for-navigating-directories-and-opening-files). The 'jump' function is as useful as promised and has led me to investigate `dired` seriously. One snag is that I cannot group directories above files in `dired` buffers. I have tried putting the following in my `.emacs.d` file but it has no effect, presumably because I am running on Windows.

```
(setq dired-listing-switches "--group-directories-first -alh")
```

How can I achieve grouped directories above files in `dired` buffers in Windows 7?

[EDIT] as per the answer below, [`dired-sort-menu`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortMenu) does seem to work - see following screenshot.

[image: dired-sort-menu screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DiredSortMenu](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortMenu) may help you with that.  It has an option for sorting with directories first.

If you dont't use a package like that, you may find the "ls" options supported in Windows by doing C-h f RET insert-directory (as you guessed, "--group-directories-first" is not supported).

Answer (score 6):

There is actually an option for this if you're using the ls emulation, as on Windows:

```
(setq ls-lisp-dirs-first t)
```

See (customize-group 'ls-lisp) for all the options. There are some useful ones -

```
; hide the link count, user, and group columns - default is '(links uid gid)
(setq ls-lisp-verbosity nil)

; use ISO dates (the first is for recent dates, second for old dates)
(setq ls-lisp-format-time-list '("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
(setq ls-lisp-use-localized-time-format t)
```

Giving you a listing like this -

```
total used in directory 27734 available 171804716
dr-xr-xr-x       40960 2015-02-12 00:47 .
drwxrwxrwx       16384 2015-02-11 17:37 ..
dr-xr-xr-x       32768 2015-02-07 09:41 bookshelf
drwxrwxrwx       12288 2014-12-03 00:06 library
drwxrwxrwx        8192 2014-08-17 08:21 office
dr-xr-xr-x       16384 2015-02-10 19:54 projects
-rw-rw-rw-       14073 2015-01-31 17:25 android.org
-rw-rw-rw-       65736 2015-02-05 17:09 archive.org
```

Answer (score 0):

`dired` can either use `ls` to get the list of files, or use some internal Elisp code instead.  By default under Windows it does not use `ls` (in other systems, by default it uses `ls`).  The `--group-directories-first` option is not supported by the Elisp code, so if you want to use it, you need to set `ls-lisp-use-insert-directory-program` to nil so as to tell dired to use `ls` (and of course, that will only work if/when you have a proper `ls.exe` installed which does support `--group-directories-first`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [DiredSortMenu](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortMenu) is your friend.  And [`dired-sort-menu+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/dired-sort-menu%2b.el) adds a few tweaks. Also, this EmacsWiki page has a bit more about sorting [directories first](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortDirectoriesFirst), FWIW.

Comment: Thanks. Is `dired-sort-menu+.el` a pure extension i.e. does it need `dired-sort-menu` or is it standalone?

Comment: It requires `dired-sort-menu.el` (automatically) --- it just enhances it a bit. It binds 3 keys differently, to avoid conflicts; it avoids defining two options if you cannot use them (depending on your context); and it fixes a null `buffer-file-name` bug.

Answer (score 0):

In Emacs 25.3.1, directories get sorted by setting:

```
(setq dired-listing-switches "-al --group-directories-first")
```